# Git Branch Off A Branch

Tags: git, github

I'm working off of master and create Branch 'A'.

Branch 'A' contains HTML/CSS/JS to create a 'widget'.

While this code is being reviewed I also want to work on creating tests for this 'widget'.

I can't work off of master yet because Branch 'A' hasn't been merged.  But I need a way to work off of Branch 'A' without making updates to it while the code is being reviewed to push to master.

I figure I need to make Branch 'B' off of Branch 'A' so that I can continue working off of the code I had already created.

Question 1.  How can I do this in git?

Question 2. Once I merge Branch 'A' to master, will that also include Branch 'B' even though i'm not done yet?

Question 3. Can I merge Branch 'B' independent of Branch 'A'?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Question 1. How can I do this in git?

```
git checkout branch_a
git pull
git checkout -b branch_b
```

You'll then have the commits from `branch_a` in your new `branch_b`.

> Question 2. Once I merge Branch 'A' to master, will that also include Branch 'B' even though i'm not done yet?

No, they're entirely separate branches so only the commits from `branch_a` will exist in master.

> Question 3. Can I merge Branch 'B' independent of Branch 'A'?

Sort of a two-pronged approach here. If you want to take `branch_a` commits with you, then you can merge `branch_b` into master at any time, although that sort of voids the purpose.

Given that `branch_b`'s tests presumably depend on `branch_a` it would seem silly to merge B before A.

Once you have merged A into master, you will probably need to rebase `branch_b` onto the new master, and get rid of all of the original commits you took over from `branch_a`, since they all now exist in master:

```
# Assume A merged into master
git fetch
# Rebase interactively
git rebase -i origin/master
# Exclude (skip or comment out) the commits that were from A, leaving only B
# Rebasing (n/n).....
git push origin branch_b --force
```

This will give you a fresh `branch_b` from master, where the commits from A now exist, and you won't have merge conflicts when you merge B into master.

The force push will only be required if you've already pushed `branch_b` to origin. If you haven't, no problem.

Answer (score 7):

It's trivial - you can create a branch off any branch in git.

If you're on branch A, simply do `git checkout -b B` and you'll have a new branch starting at A. It will be separate from A, and changes from A will not be reflected in B.

When A is merged to master, the merge will not bring in the commits on B.

You can't manage B to master independently - branch B also contains the commits that were on A at the time it was created, so merging B will also bring in those commits as well. It is possible to bring in just the changes from B (without A) using an interactive rebase or a cherry-pick, but that's fairly advanced and probably not what you want to do.

Another thing you'll want to do - once you branch off B, you'll probably end up making changes to A due to your code review. Be sure to rebase B on top of A to keep everything up to date, otherwise you'll have some pain later when you go to merge your tests into master.

Comment: Rebasing B onto the updated A is one option, but if anyone else might have pulled B you should instead just *merge* A *into* B, make any changes needed to account for the changes, and then either merge B into A and thence to master or directly to master, depending on your branching structure. Why do this? Rebasing rewrites history, and rewriting published history is a Bad Thing in git.

Comment: Oh, agreed. In general when I'm in this situation B is a completely private branch, so rebasing is easier and cleaner than generating a bunch of extra merge commits.

Comment: @Darael rewriting published history is bad in theory, sure, but sometimes it's necessary to achieve things like a cleaner history, removing bad commits etc, and it's only going to be a problem if the repository is popular, commonly used, etc.

Comment: @RobbieAverill a cleaner history is, in my view, not worth the pain that results if anybody else tries to pull from a repo they cloned before the rewrite. Admittedly for things like branches published only for pull requests it makes a certain amount of sense, but that's only because the only person who should ever pull it is working *with* you on the rewrite. As for removing bad commits, that's fine in private branches but as soon as it's published that is *precisely* what `git revert` is for.

Comment: @Darael I agree with everything you said. Reverting commits for me is still messy, but if the branch is active elsewhere; you're right - it's worth doing over a rebase

Comment: "rebase B on top of A" would you run the rebase command on the B branch or the A? It reads as if I should be on branch A and run the rebase command with B, but that doesn't seem right

Comment: I meant, while on branch B, run `git rebase A`. This will take the changes you made to B and put them on top of the latest work on A, leaving B in a fully updated state containing both the latest stuff in A and the work already done in B.